# Creation of a matrix

Tags: matrix

I would like to write the matrix

v[s_,ss_,qi,qj] :=( {{a/(2 r) DiracDelta[s - ss], a/r(HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) + r] - HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) - r])}, {a/r(HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) + r] - HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) - r]), a/(2 r) DiracDelta[s - ss]}})

S[z_, i_, j_] := S[z, i, j] =Integrate[Sum[1/(M[[qi]]*M[[qj]])*u[s,i, qi]*v[s,ss, qi, qj]*udot[ss, qj, j], {qi, 2}, {qj, 2}], {ss, 0, z}], {s, 0, z}];

where

M[qi]={1,1,1,1}
M[qj]={1,1,1,1}

Comment: What is `s`, did you mean to index it as well? Did you mean `KroneckerDelta` instead of `DiracDelta`?

Comment: I mean DiracDelta.

Comment: But the right expansion of S is:S[z_, i_, j_] = 
 NIntegrate[ NIntegrate[Sum[1/(M[[qi]]*M[[qj]])*u[s, i, qi]*vqiqj[s - ss]*udot[ss, qj, j], {qi, 2}, {qj, 2}], {ss, 0, z}],{s, , 0, z}]

Comment: Please edit your question instead of giving info in the comments.

Comment: Some hints: 1. You are using the variables `qi` and `qj` outside of the integrals in which they are defined. 2. `qi` and `qj` are real-valued integration variables but you are using them as integer-valued indices. 3. You have too many underscores in your definition of `S`, see [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html). 4. There's an extraneous comma in your summation over `z`. 5. Your definition of `vqiqj` should be in terms of a variable `ds=s-ss`, not in terms of `s-ss`. There's probably more.

Comment: Could you please provide a well-typeset version of formulae?