# Definition of a matrix

Tags: matrix, syntax

```
v = 
  {{a/(2 r) DiracDelta[s - ss]}, 
   {(a/r)[HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) + r] - HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) - r]]},
   {a/(2 r) DiracDelta[s - ss]}, 
   {(a/r)[HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) + r] - HeavisideTheta[(s - ss) - r]]}}
```

Do you know how to define a matrix `v` as a function of `s`, `ss`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creation of a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202811/creation-of-a-matrix) by the same person. Maybe you can edit your other post instead of re-posting?

Comment: When I write v[s, ss]:=... the answer is failed. When I write v={{. ..}} is correct but for v[[1.,1.]] the matrix gives me the elements 11 of the matrix. I would like a matrix v[s, ss] as a function.